# Implement timer and display time in a textbox

Tags: c#, timer

I am very new to C# and hence please bare with my silly questions.

I want to implement a timer in C#, which should be able to print the lapsed time since timer has started.

I have a button "start", text box, and button "End". Upon clicking button "start" timer should start and time should be displayed in text box until I push on button "End". Once I click button "End", timer has to stop and text box should be showing lapsed time.

Comment: What have you implemented?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx  You should be able to figure this out from here.

Answer (score 0):

Stop Button Click Event:

```
    private void EndBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
```

Start Button Click Event:

```
    private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();

    }
```

Timer Tick Event:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants and absolutely not how Timer works.